# Unicode error while parsing table in python markdown

Tags: python, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I am using Python Markdown to parse the following table.

```
Escape sequences |  Character represented
-----------------|--------------------------
\b      |   Backspace
\t      |   Tab
\f      |   Form feed
\n      |   New line
\r      |   Carriage return
\\      |   Backslash
\'      |   Single quote
\"      |   Double quote
\uNNNN  |   where NNNN is a unicode number, with this escape sequence you can print unicode characters
```

Here is the code i am using

```
html = markdown.markdown(str, extensions=['markdown.extensions.tables', 'markdown.extensions.fenced_code',
                                          'markdown.extensions.toc', 'markdown.extensions.wikilinks'])
print(html)
```

and here is the error

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 1000-1001: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your input string contains the backslash symbol which has [special meaning](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html). To let it work your input data should look like:

```
Escape sequences |  Character represented
-----------------|--------------------------
\\b      |   Backspace
\\t      |   Tab
\\f      |   Form feed
\\n      |   New line
\\r      |   Carriage return
\\\\      |   Backslash
\\'      |   Single quote
\\"      |   Double quote
\\uNNNN  |   where NNNN is a unicode number, with this escape sequence you can print unicode characters
```

i.e. backslash should be escaped by itself.
The dumb way to reach this - probably just make some preprocessing before parsing with markdown:

```
str.replace('\\', '\\\\')  # yes, here too :)
```